# What is the best sort algorithm for continuously (NOT FIXED) input of random numbers?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose I have a system that receives one by one as an input continuously random numbers all the time `(0,5,2,10,6,20......)` ,

My purpose is to sort them with the best performance.

So the output size will be increased after each iteration and the input is sequential .

I thought to use either insertion sort or BST , but I don't sure what is better for this issue ,as i know insertion sort is `O(n-n^2)` and BST insertion is `O(log(n))`

Please , any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want to sort them according to arrival time you just add each new number to the end of the list....

Comment: I've edited my question , i want just to sort them (0,2,5,6....)

Comment: What is the meaning of O(n-n^2) ???

Comment: @Yves Daoust Insertion sort: the best is O(n) the worst case O(n^2)

Comment: using skiplist would give you O(log n) for inserting

Comment: As the numbers are being received, when and how often and how does the system need to be able to retrieve numbers previously stored in to the structure? The how part would be asking how the sorted numbers are to be accessed, such as by index, or perhaps occasionally retrieving the entire set. If retrieval is intermittent, then the numbers could be partially sorted as they are received, and only fully sorted when asked for using something similar to a bottom up merge sort for a linked list using a small array of references or pointers.

Comment: @rcgldr : i need to sort them each time new number arrives

Comment: You need to be more specific. Saying "I need to sort them each time" does not really answer @rcgldr 's question. You'll have to compromise somewhere between very fast insertion and very fast retrieval at some point, you can't have both, so be very specific about your needs. For instance, we still don't know if access by index in O(1) is required. If that's the case, then you're doomed to use a sorted array, and you can't do better than O(n) for insertion. Each specific answer you give will point you closer and closer to the best compromise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to sort every time an element is added, this is not a sorting problem but an insertion problem. Any sorting algorithm will be overkill.

If your data must be stored in an array, you can't spare shifting the elements and the solution is Ω(N). This is efficiently achieved by straight insertion (O(N)). (Dichotomic search followed by insertion will take less comparisons but it is not sure that you will notice a difference.)

If you have more freedom, a BST is indeed a more efficient solution. If you need absolute guarantee on the worst-case cost (O(Log N)), the BST needs to be balanced (so AVL, Red-Black... up to your taste). If your data is sufficiently random, this might be unnecessary.

If your data has special properties (for example small discrete range), ad-hoc solutions can do. In the given example, a simple counting histogram will achieve O(1) update time.

Comment: my data it just random numbers range from 0 to 1M , and the output can be array or tree , it is according to the best performance

Comment: Continuously all the time...a lot - the time when server is up , can be more than 1M numbers

Comment: @VitalyTarasiuk: there is nothing I can do with such vague information. "All the time" is impossible if you must keep all data: the machine will sooner or later overflow.

Comment: Then this is too small to justify the histogram approach, not per se, but because listing the sorted values will be slow. You should answer @Thomas' question.

Comment: Late comment: sorting a "continuously input" seems to be an XY problem. If million values are received, I doubt that the sorted whole million will be looked at every time a new value arrives. The OP should specify why/when exactly he wants his data sorted.

Answer (score 3):

I think that using some BST that promises `O(log n)` performacne (like AVL, black-red, etc.) is your best option.

Printing out the current data is done using an in-order traversal of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is efficient on small inputs (less than 1000), otherwise since it takes running time of O(n^2) it will grow in complexity very fast, if you are not sure how big your input would grow to, then use quick sort or heap sort that have running time of O(nlogn) which is much faster than O(n^2).

Comment: Why not use some BST (AVL, black-red, etc.) and then additions are `O(log n)`?

Comment: @Shadi Shaaban - quick sort & heap sort are using fix size of input....i have sequential order ( not fixed)

Comment: I see, in this case I would go with @shapiro suggestion, using AVL, 2-4 or Red-Black trees would be very efficient as it has O(log n) for insertion.

Comment: what about insertion sort ? as i know it used for "online sorting algorithms" like this, am i right ? Or maybe  balanced trees ?

Comment: In your case, since you are using sorted array every time, the running time for insertion sort would be O(n) which is still worse than balanced trees O(log n).

Comment: @VitalyTarasiuk: "quick sort & heap sort are using fix size of input...": this is wrong.

Comment: why not ? for example in "heap sort" initially you must build the heap, which iterate over the input size  - which is fix

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors that will weigh into the efficiency of your solution:

- number of READS finding the insertion point
- number of WRITES (e.g. shifts, rebalance) inserting
- total memory/locality (impacts cache misses) The magnitude of the constant (K) is relevant as it effects how many elements fit in each cache level.
- branch prediction misses

Note that these will vary more based on the data structure than the algorithm, which seems to always be a variant of insertion sort since you resort with each element addition

```
Data Structure | READS  | WRITES | Memory     | locality | Branches
---------------|--------|--------|------------|----------|---------
Sorted Vector  |O(logN) | O(N)   | O(N)       | high     | high (FFTFFT)
Linked List    |O(N)    | O(1)   | O(K*N)     | low      | low  (FFFFFFFFFFT)
Red Black Tree |O(logN) | O(K)   | O(K*NlogN) | low      | high (FFTFFT)
Btree 16 node  |O(logN) | O(16)  | O(NlogN)   | medium   | medium (FFTF)
```

** K indicates a notably higher constant than other solutions with same O()*

The optimal solution can vary based on the current architectural constraints.   If memory/cache sizes are small a sorted vector will likely be optimal.
If Branch misses are expensive a linked list will likely be optimal as branches except the last will all be false

But it seems if you use a *Btree* with a large number of nodes `P`you will gain the locality and memory efficiency of a vector, have the indexed O(logN) READ speed, and will limit the number of WRITES to O(`P`) not O(N).   I'd start with `P` of 16, and then use binary search to optimize `P`,

Unfortunately the real answer is try them all and benchmark with your use case

Comment: Sure, it eliminates the shifting problem. It becomes a finding problem. That is, you have to walk the list sequentially in order to find the insertion spot. That's probably going to take just as much time as shifting items in an array.

Comment: @JimMischel changed my mind to Btree, but did a better job explaining the trade offs

Answer (score 1):

The original question doesn't make it clear how often data has to retrieved while it is receiving numbers, or how the numbers are to be retrieved (by index, just the smallest, just the largest, or all of them, ... ).

One option is to use the logic for a bottom up merge sort for linked lists, which uses a small (26 to 32 elements) array of references or pointers, each pointing to a list. Array[i] is a reference or a pointer to a list containing (2 to the power i) nodes, array[0] points to a list of size 1, array[1] -> list of size 2, array[2] -> list of size 4, with the last member of the array pointing to a list unlimited in size. Nodes are inserted into the array one at a time, which corresponds to receiving numbers one at a time.

The issue is that the data is stored in array of lists, so only partially sorted. To get a fully sorted list, the array of lists are merged into a single list. Normally this is only done after all data is stored into the array.

Wiki article for bottom up merge sort on linked lists:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

This method provides a fast average insertion time, with occasional long times. Every other number is just stored into array[0]. Inputs on power of 2 boundaries involve multiple merge steps, the 16th input ends up merging two lists of 8 numbers, the 1024th input ends up merging two lists of 512 numbers.

As already mentioned, a binary search tree (occasionally rebalanced), may be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depents on how do you want to use the result.

For example: If you give in a lot of numbers, and you are using BST for storing them, you need more than 1000 steps to find the index 1000. If you store the sorted result inside an array, you only need 1 step (return index[1000]).

If you only need the highest or lowest number and then you delete it out of your list. After that you need the next highest or lowest number, you are a lot of faster with a heap.

Also remember, if the randomnumbers are somehow sorted, the BST looks like a list and then you don't have O(log n) but O(n) for inserting.

There are a lot of more things you have to think about. So please tell us for what do you need this

Comment: also a skiplist can help you

Comment: I need only sorted data structure as output , it could be anything (array,tree, etc'). But with minimum processing/ response time

Comment: I think a skiplist is extrem fast and easy to implement